# How to add custom HTML Tag with Zend Form Description

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

Consider I would like to display

Checkbox, Checkbox label and an image there after.

How can I create a view for the same using Zend Engine Form

I tried as follows

```
    $this->addElement(
            'Checkbox',
            "$key",
            array(
             'label'=>$value,
                'checkedValue' => "$key",
                'uncheckedValue' => '',
                'checked' => true,
             'disabled' => false,
          )
        );

     $element = $this->getElement($key);         


       $element->setDecorators(
   array(
     'ViewHelper',
     array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt', 'class'=>'hidden')),
     array('Description',array('escape'=>false,'tag'=>' span')), //escape false because I want html output
    )
   );

     $element->setDescription('<img name="help_'.$key.'" id="help_'.$key.'" src="/application/modules/User/externals/images/what-is-this.gif"/>');

$element->setDescription('<img name="help_'.$key.'" id="help_'.$key.'" src="/application/modules/User/externals/images/what-is-this.gif"/>');
```

But which showing checkbox, description image and checkbox label as superscript.

Any help please

Answer (score 20):

```
$element->getDecorator('Description')->setEscape(false);
```

This will prevent escaping description content.

Comment: Also useful to know that if you'd like to unescape the description set directly on the form itself ($this), you can use $this->getDecorator('Description')->setOption('escape', false);

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [AnyMarkup Decorator](http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/62/anymarkup-decorator).

You can add that decorator into your element decorator list, specifying the markup for the image with an APPEND position.